# What may cause a script to download an html doc instead of a pdf?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, export-to-pdf

I have a script that a developer created for me. It downloads a pdf from a Google Sheet. This script has been working for more than a year, then starting this past Tuesday, when I try to download the pdf, it saves it as an HTML document instead.

I have been working in my G Suite account, where I typically use this script. However, when I shared the Google Sheet with a regular Gmail account, I can still download the sheet as a pdf to drive.

I tried running it in the account of another user in the same G Suite domain, and it also produces an HTML doc.

The developer says the script works, it must be a setting in the G Suite. G Suite help says they can't provide support because it is a script.

Comment: Hmm ... it *might* be a MIME settings issue. The user browser isn't detecting that the document is a PDF and so is defaulting to the type of the page. Wild guess.

Comment: Can you please share your script?

Comment: I am not sure how much of this is relevant, so I included it all. Also, there are two other scripts "Picker.html" and "Reset_PDF_name_and_Others_Attending.gs". I don't think these are relevant, but if you need them I can share these as well.

Comment: @bugmagnet: Would your suggestion still be relevant if I was able to get the script to run in the SAME browser but in a DIFFERNT gmail account?

Comment: Post the relevant part of the script and / or sample HTML (or at least clarify if the HTML you get consists of a document you wanted to export).

Comment: @OlegValter: yes, as far as I can tell it is the correct information, but just in HTML not pdf.

Comment: @OlegValter I didn't write the script. I'm not sure what parts a relevant. When I try to post the entire script, I get an error it is too long. I'm new to the forum. Not sure it there is a different way to post it.

Comment: @DavidPhelan then you will have to either give your developer access to the GSuite account (preferrable with IAM permissions enough to do the job), if they are sure about the root cause or hire another one. I apologize, but we are not a support platform, not are we a forum. Although someone might've had the same problem, then they will either post an answer or at least comment about it.

Comment: @OlegValter Thank you for your response. I apologize. Google Support directed me to this forum.

Comment: @DavidPhelan - no worries, you may still get some help. I personally do not know of any "setting" in GSuite that would magically make all exported pdf to become HTML documents. So we need to see the code to be able to analyze it. If the dev does not know the answer but is willing to help you - ask them to post here, most likely they will be able to answer clarifications from users and provide reproducible examples.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old however I had the same issue and found that if you have the setting "share with anyone with the link" you get the pdf where as when access is restricted to specific people you get the html